# Can't fix this issue in Edit Text Linear Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I did a small coding based on the input count, it will display the number of check box and radio button. Here, everything goes fine. But I'm stuck with the Edit Text. If I enter any value to the first Edit Text and click the button, the concern value is displaying in the left top corner. I need it to display below as like checkbox and radio button is displayed. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

**XML layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
        android:hint="Enter no" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="05dp"
        android:text="Edit Text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:hint="Enter no" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Check Box" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Radio Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java MainActivity:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout mLayout;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private Button mButton;
    Button abutton;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick());
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("New text");


        final EditText button2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                int number=Integer.parseInt(button2.getText().toString());
                addRadioButtons(number);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                int number=Integer.parseInt(button2.getText().toString());
                addCheckBox(number);
            }
        });
    }
    public void addRadioButtons(int number) {

        for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
                rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + i);
                rdbtn.setText("Radio " + rdbtn.getId());
                ll.addView(rdbtn);
            }
            ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)).addView(ll);
        }

    }

    public void addCheckBox(int number) {

        for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
                ch.setId((row * 2) + i);
                ch.setText("Check " + ch.getId());
                ll.addView(ch);
            }
            ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)).addView(ll);
        }

    }

    private OnClickListener onClick() {
        return new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mEditText.getText().toString()));
            }
        };
    }

    private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
        final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        textView.setText("" + text);
        return textView;
    }


}
```

Comment: ` I need it to display below as like checkbox and radio button is displayed` ... Below of what would you like to display these TextViews? Below `RadioButton` button?

Comment: @gunar: First Text View, then check box then radio button..As of now, it is displaying only check box and radio button..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the changes like this in your XML layout

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:hint="Enter no" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Check Box" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Radio Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:hint="Enter no" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Check Box" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Radio Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
        android:hint="Enter no" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="05dp"
        android:text="Edit Text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewbutton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginRight="05dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Edit Text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textviewbutton2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:hint="Enter no" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Check Box" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Radio Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:text="Auto Pilot"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:text="Auto Pilot"
            android:textColor="#333333" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radiogroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:text="Auto Pilot"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:text="Auto Pilot"
            android:textColor="#333333" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radiogroup2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:text="Auto Pilot"
            android:textColor="#333333" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:text="Auto Pilot"
            android:textColor="#333333" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Cant get your answer..can you please brief it ?

Comment: can you pls give me a screen shot which you want to make

Comment: see this screenshot mediafire.com/view/m6l4q71av9x43h7 I need the edit text should display above the check1 check 2 check 3.

Comment: see i m edit my code and in my new answer your complete code just take it :)

Comment: Dinesh is trying to add checkboxes and radiobuttons dynamically ... right? You have provided a static layout solution

Comment: its not difficult dear just give the same radio nd chk box button at dynamic time  with same credential like below layout id width height it will work simple i think

Comment: LinearLayout child_insidenew_layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
     child_insidenew_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams child_inside_paramsnew = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
     child_insidenew_layout.setLayoutParams(child_inside_paramsnew);  and  dinish take all view which he want an add view in layout   child_inside_layout.addView(lineimage, lineimage_params);

Answer (score 0):

Change you full layout to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
        android:hint="Enter no" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="05dp"
        android:text="Edit Text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Check Box" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:text="Radio Button" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:hint="Enter no" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

No Java code changes, but you're getting a `NumberFormatException` if nothing or invalid content is entered in second edit text and the user is pressing the second button.

Comment: see this screenshot   http://www.mediafire.com/view/m6l4q71av9x43h7    I need the edit text should display above the check1 check 2 check 3..

Comment: updated the layout for what you need ... check it out

Comment: I tried the changed code..still the edit text is below the check box...I need it here..please look at this screenshot..http://www.mediafire.com/view/m6l4q71av9x43h7/Capture.PNG

Comment: man, you really need to learn how to post correct questions ... will update the answer shortly ...

Comment: sorry yaar..can you get my question?

Comment: There, changed. Give it a try now. If it works and fulfills your needs don't forget to upvote and accept answers